# Where has the options-attribute gone in selenium v.4.11?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

so I have this code where I connect to a rotating proxy (so I get a new IP address for every request):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

PROXY = "ROTATING-PROXY-IP:PORT"

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={PROXY}')
dr = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(), options=chrome_options)
while True:
    dr.get("https://ipv4.webshare.io/")
    print(dr.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "body").text)
    dr.start_session(dr.capabilities)
```

To get a new IP, I just need to run start_session() and pass the options of the browser. This worked fine in selenium 4.10. After updating to 4.13, I noticed that the structure of the capabilities changed and they also don't include the chrome_options (like --proxy-server) anymore (before I used driver.options.to_capabilities(), but the options-attribute is gone). However, as the IP of the rotating proxy doesn't change, I thought it may work anyways, but the code fails when running start_session() with the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/niggoo/PycharmProjects/my_project/test.py", line 17, in <module>
    dr.start_session(dr.capabilities)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 289, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 344, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: unrecognized capability: chrome
```

Chrome/Chromedriver Version: 117 (mac-arm64)
Python 3.10

How can I update my code so it works again?
Thanks a lot!

EDIT: I found out that the change was made in version 4.11. The WebDriver Object does not have the Options attribute anymore. I found nothing about this in the selenium changelogs - how can I access the options now?